# Accept user input in a switch statement

Tags: java, input, switch-statement

Is it possible to assign user input from within a switch statement to a variable?

### My code:

```
case 1: //ask the user to input a subject code
            System.out.println("Please enter a Subject Code");
            String subjectCode = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter subject code", "ITC100");
            subject.isValidCode(subjectCode);
```

The input doesn't get assigned to the String subjectCode?
I  tried `input.next()` but it did not work.

Comment: Assuming `input` is `Scanner`, use `input.nextLine()` before calling `input.next()`.

Comment: thanks - sorry stupid question! named the scanner wrong....

Answer (score 0):

In following code I'm assigning subject code when the **JOptionPane** pop up.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


    public class InputSwitch {

        private static String subjectCode;

        public static void switchInputTest(int choice){
            switch(choice){
            case 1:
            System.out.println("Please enter a Subject Code");
            subjectCode = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter subject code", "ITC100");

            }
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            switchInputTest(1);
            System.out.println(subjectCode);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for your question

```
  case 1:
            System.out.println("Enter your subject code: ");
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            String subjectCode = scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println("subject code " + subjectCode);

            subject.isValidCode(subjectCode);
}
```